# What is the recommended Process for using QuickBlox in iOS Share Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox successfully in a a main iOS app and would like to extend the features in to a Share Extension using the cocoapod 'QuickBlox', '~> 2.7.5'. I needs to send the message in the background without opening the main application.

I am using the code below without any success to first setup sending text  only.

```
    [QBRequest logInWithUserLogin:USERNAME password:PASSWORD successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {
        if (user) {
            user.login = USERNAME;
            user.password = PASSWORD;
            [[QBChat instance] connectWithUser:user completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

                QBChatDialog *chatDialog = [[QBChatDialog alloc] initWithDialogID:[settingsDict valueForKey:@"sendingID"] type:QBChatDialogTypeGroup];

                QBChatMessage *messagetosend = [QBChatMessage message];
                messagetosend.senderID = userQBID;
                messagetosend.text = self.contentText;
                messagetosend.dateSent = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-12.0f sinceDate:[NSDate date]];

                [chatDialog joinWithCompletionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    [chatDialog sendMessage:messagetosend completionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
                    }];

                }];
            }
             ];
        }
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response) { }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the message via REST. Sending via REST doesn't need to connect to chat and join in the dialog.

```
NSUInteger senderID = //Current User ID
QBChatMessage *message = [QBChatMessage message];
message.text = intent.content;
message.senderID = senderID;
message.markable = YES;
message.deliveredIDs = @[@(senderID)];
message.readIDs = @[@(senderID)];
message.dialogID = dialogID;
message.dateSent = [NSDate date];

[QBRequest sendMessage:message successBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response, QBChatMessage * _Nonnull createdMessage) {

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response) {

}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't see any class method named _sendMessage_. Is there any alternative in QB 2.7.5?

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature was added in QB iOS SDK 2.9.1.[Changelog](https://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Framework_changelog)

Comment: OK I tried updating the Share extension in QB SDK 2.9.1 but it crashes on send with an error: 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[QBRequest sendMessage:successBlock:errorBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3b735c'

Comment: @Randy, We have tested it and this issue is not reproducible in our samples, please create the issue on [QB github](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/new)  and attach sample project with it being reproducible.

Comment: Thanks @Guru_quickblox_support